# Is `std::common_type` associative?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, types, metaprogramming

The template class `std::common_type` calculates a common type to a variadic type list. [It is defined using the return type of the ternary operator `x:y?z` recursively.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) From that definition it is not obvious to me, whether calculating a `std::common_type<X,Y>` is associative, i. e. whether

```
using namespace std;
static_assert( is_same<common_type< X, common_type<Y,Z>::type    >::type,
                       common_type<    common_type<X,Y>::type, Z >::type>::value, "" );
```

will never throw a compile-time error for all types `X`, `Y` and `Z` for which the `is_same<...>` expression is valid.

Please note, that I'm NOT asking whether

```
static_assert( is_same<common_type<X,Y>::type,
                       common_type<Y,X>::type>::value, "" );
```

will ever fire. It will obviously not. The above is a whole different question.

Please note also, that the specification of `std::common_type` slightly changed in C++14 and will probably change again in C++17. So the answers may be different for different versions of the standard.

Comment: Will you accept a case where `(X,(Y,Z))` has a common type, but `(X,Y)`, and hence `(X,Y),Z`, does not? Or do you want them both to resolve to a type, but different ones. 'Cause I'm pretty stuck trying to construct a case for the latter, and strongly suspect it isn't possible; any two chains of conversions will cause an ambiguity.

Comment: It's certainly the case that the static_assertion can fail to compile, because there is no common type. I assume the question is asking about the case where all the `common_type` types are valid, but `is_same` is false.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thanks for the hint. Fixed the question.

Comment: Apparently you can make it not-associative. But that doesn't matter, if it not associative it is because there is a logical inconsistency in your design. It would be like defining `operator==` in a way that is not consistent with logic.

Comment: I assumed this was more of an academic interest, but either way, I disagree with "that doesn't matter... there is a logical inconsistency in your design" because (in the general sense) associativity is not always desired, and substitution failure can be. I can at least think of a tangential counter-example to the `operator==` argument: a double cast down to a float may equal another float, but a float cast up to a double can easily fail equality. (Using this impl. warrants documentation, but casting both to LCM (float here) or both to GCM (double here) to enforce assoc. is edge case spackle.)

Comment: (cont.) - this makes more sense if you have composites (possibly heterogeneous), symbols without closed-form evaluations, types prone to 'gimbal lock' in intermediate representations, etc. - you would be justified to point to conventional arithmetic transitivity/associativity/etc. for the simple example, but maybe not once the other 'intuitive' properties break down. And before you point it out - of course this would all amount to nit-picking in any other context, but not when you're ironing out rigorously-defined properties and hard guarantees. If "you can make it [non]-assoc.", *it isn't*.

Comment: Oh, and sorry for the tone and rant, I haven't slept. Hopefully I at least made sense.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This fails on MinGW-w64(gcc 4.9.1). Also fails on VS2013 and (thanks Baum mit Augen) on gcc5.2 or clang 3.7 with libc++.

```
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

struct Z;
struct X{operator Z();};
struct Y{operator X();};
struct Z{operator Y();};

static_assert( is_same<common_type<X,Y>::type,
                       common_type<Y,X>::type>::value, "" ); // PASS

static_assert( is_same<common_type<X,Z>::type,
                       common_type<Z,X>::type>::value, "" ); // PASS

static_assert( is_same<common_type<Y,Z>::type,
                       common_type<Z,Y>::type>::value, "" ); // PASS

static_assert( is_same<common_type< X, common_type<Y,Z>::type    >::type,
                       common_type<    common_type<X,Y>::type, Z >::type>::value, "" ); // FAIL...
```

Comment: Also fails with gcc5.2 and clang 3.7 with libc++.

Comment: Also fails on clang 3.8.0 and gcc 7.0.0 (snapshot)

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <type_traits>

struct T2;
struct T1 {
    T1(){}
    T1(int){}
    operator T2();
};
struct T2 {
    operator int() { return 0; }
};
struct T3 {
    operator int() { return 0; }
};
T1::operator T2() { return T2(); }

using namespace std;
using X = T1;
using Y = T2;
using Z = T3;
int main()
{

    true?T2():T3(); // int
    static_assert(std::is_same<std::common_type_t<T2,
                                                  T3>,
                               int>::value,
                  "Not int");

    true?T1():(true?T2():T3()); // T1
    static_assert(std::is_same<std::common_type_t<T1,
                                                  std::common_type_t<T2,
                                                                     T3>>,
                               T1>::value,
                  "Not T1");

    // -----------------------------------------

    true?T1():T2(); // T2
    static_assert(std::is_same<std::common_type_t<T1,
                                                  T2>,
                               T2>::value,
                  "Not T2");

    true?(true?T1():T2()):T3(); // int
    static_assert(std::is_same<std::common_type_t<std::common_type_t<T1,
                                                                     T2>,
                                                  T3>,
                               int>::value,
                  "Not int");

    // -----------------------------------------

    static_assert( is_same<common_type_t< X, common_type_t<Y,Z>    >,
                           common_type_t<    common_type_t<X,Y>, Z > >::value,
                    "Don't match");
}
```

Ouch! The mental gymnastics here hurt my head, but I came up with a case that fails to compile, printing "Don't match", with gcc 4.9.2 and with "C++14" (gcc 5.1) on [ideone](http://ideone.com/dwzCQO). Now whether or not that is conforming is a different matter...

Now the claim is for class types, `std::common_type_t<X, Y>` should be either `X` or `Y`, but I have coerced `std::common_type_t<T2, T3>` into converting to `int`.

Please try with other compilers and let me know what happens!

Comment: Also fires with clang3.7 + libc++.

Comment: fires with mingw-w64 too. VS2013 triggers all of them (and some other errors) except the "Not T2" one. Granted, VS is not know for its conformity to the Standard...

Comment: My interpretation of the standard suggests that the second case is ill-formed because int and T1 can convert to each other. This makes them ineligible to be operands 2 and 3 of operator:?

Comment: @RichardHodges `int` converts to `T1`. `T1` doesn't convert to `int` (one-user-defined-conversion-only rule).

Answer (score 2):

It's not associative! Here's a program where it fails:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Z;
struct X { X(Z); }; // enables conversion from Z to X
struct Y { Y(X); }; // enables conversion from X to Y
struct Z { Z(Y); }; // enables conversion from Y to Z

using namespace std;    
static_assert( is_same<common_type< X, common_type<Y,Z>::type    >::type,
                       common_type<    common_type<X,Y>::type, Z >::type>::value, 
               "std::common_type is not associative." );
```

The idea is simple: The following diagram shows, what `common_type` calculates:

```
    X,Y -> Y
    Y,Z -> Z
    X,Z -> X
```

The first line is logical, since `X` can be converted to `Y`, but not vice versa. The same for the other two lines. Once `X` and `Y` are combined and recombined with `Z` we get `Z`. On the other hand, combining `Y` and `Z` and the combining `X` with the result gives `X`. Therefore the results are different.

The fundamental reason for this being possible is that convertibility is not transitive, i. e. if `X` is convertible to `Y` and `Y` convertible to `Z` it does not follow that `X` is convertible to `Z`. If convertibility were transitive, then conversions would work both ways and hence the `common_type` could not be calculated unambiguously and lead to a compile time error.

This reasoning is independent of the standard version. It applies to C++11, C++14 and the upcoming C++17.

Comment: Yes, but I have philosophical concerns about three categories than can be mapped into each other but only cyclically. I would say that is not associative in the language but it should be, in the same sense that `operator==` should be implemented in a way that `T a = b; assert(a == b);`